# Issue in SQL statement to get value in combination of 3 values

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

Prod_Oth_Id ||| Prod_Code ||||| Prod_Details |||||||||| Prod_Value |

```
    1     | BR25MAON  | 4            | 9          |
    2     | BR25MAON  | 5            | 10         |
    3     | BR25MAON  | 6            | 11         |
    4     | BR25MABO  | 4            | 9          |
     5    | BR25MABO  | 5            | 10         |
     6    | BR25MABO  | 6            | 17         |
     7    | BR25GLON  | 4            | 9          |
        8 | BR25GLON  | 5            | 16         |
        9 | BR25GLON  | 6            | 11         |
       10 | BR25GLBO  | 4            | 9          |
       11 | BR25GLBO  | 5            | 16         |
       12 | BR25GLBO  | 6            | 17         |
```

I have combination of 3 prod_value for eg 9,10,11 
& I want to retrieve prodcode for for above combination which is BR25MAON

for eg if I got 9, 16, 17 then I must retrieve prodcode for this combination which is BR25GLBO

Comment: @joachim-isaksson  thanx for your answer at                                                             http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c4ab/20

Comment: Simplified the query in a new answer below, the old query may not give the correct result in all circumstances (ie 9,10,11,12 would match 9,10,11) Try the new simper query.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you are genious  you made my day thanx once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the matches and non matches, if there are 3 Prod_Values to match, there should be 3 matches and 0 non matches;

```
# 9, 10, 11

SELECT DISTINCT a.Prod_Code FROM MyTable a GROUP BY Prod_Code
HAVING SUM(a.Prod_Value NOT IN (9,10,11)) = 0               # <-- No non matches
   AND SUM(a.Prod_Value     IN (9,10,11)) = 3;              # <-- 3 matches
```

If you for example were matching `(1,2)`, the query would change to;

```
# 1, 2

SELECT DISTINCT a.Prod_Code FROM MyTable a GROUP BY Prod_Code
HAVING SUM(a.Prod_Value NOT IN (1,2)) = 0                   # <-- No non matches
   AND SUM(a.Prod_Value     IN (1,2)) = 2;                  # <-- 2 matches
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3242a/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the product code for different product value then simply use this:

```
Select Distinct Prod_Code From TableName Where Prod_Value IN (9,10,11)
```

and it will return only BR25GLBO

If you need something else please explain your requirement in detail.

Comment: This is not used because IN is the replacement of many OR conditions, and as per his requirement, AND is the useful.

Comment: see i m getting prodvalue dynamically in any of above combinations either 9,10,11 or 9,10,17 or 9,16,11 or  9,16,17 but i want to retrive common prodcode for the combinations

Comment: is there any product which may have prod_value 9 and 10 and 11,

Comment: Whatever combination you get does not matter, if those value will have different code then it will return more than on product code if you want the first one then use "select Top 1 Prod_Code ..."